# Javascript - using Option value for creating link

Tags: javascript, html-select

So this works up until it tries to populate the URL.  The alert shows the value (lowercase) but when the URL is populate it's using the innertext of the option (uppercase).

Ideally I want the options to be something like this

```
<option value="pdf">PDF - printable, viewable</option>
```

And I know there should be a way to have it dynamically create the URL instead of having a generic "homepage" link and then replacing it but the myriad things I've tried don't work because the code is trying to rewrite something that's not yet created.  I really don't want to have to work with a DOM which from my research seems to be the only way to do this piece.

Another thing I'd like is to be able to do this in a modal.  But when I put it in one, the close function doesn't work after clicking on the link.  Is that because it's no longer the active window? This is not a big deal and I've already got a lot of code here but if you want to see it, let me know.

```
<form>
Select the year:
<select id="myYear">
  <option>2018</option>
  <option>2017</option>
  <option>2016</option>
  <option>2015</option>
</select>

<br><br>

Select the month:
<select id="myMonth">
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
  <option>April</option>
  <option>May</option>
  <option>June</option>
  <option>July</option>
  <option>August</option>
  <option>September</option>
  <option>October</option>
  <option>November</option>
  <option>December</option>
</select>

<br><br>

Select Calendar or Article:
<select id="myType">
  <option>Article</option>
  <option>Calendar</option>


</select>

  <br><br>

Select PDF, Word or Webpage:
<select id="myFormat">
  <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
  <option value="doc">DOC</option>
  <option value="htm">HTM</option>

</select>

<br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click Me!">
<br><br>

</form>

<a id="myLink" href="http://www.myOrgn.org/Article/April 2017 
 Article.pdf" target="_blank">Article Homepage and Submission</a>

 </div>

 </div>
```

### Javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
     var Yrsel = document.getElementById("myYear");
     var Mnthsel = document.getElementById("myMonth");
     var Typesel = document.getElementById("myType");
     var Formatsel = document.getElementById("myFormat");
     var Formatsel1 = Formatsel.value;
     alert(Formatsel1);
   document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = "Get Link";

  if (Typesel.options[Typesel.value] = "Article") {
    document.getElementById("myLink").href = 
  "http://www.myOrg.org/Article/" + 
     Mnthsel.options[Mnthsel.selectedIndex].text + " " + 
     Yrsel.options[Yrsel.selectedIndex].text + " Article" + 
     Typesel.options[Typesel.selectedIndex].text + "." +
     Formatsel.value;

   }

   if (Typesel.options[Typesel.value] = "Calendar") {
   document.getElementById("myLink").href = 
  "http://www.myOrg.org/Article/" + 
     Mnthsel.options[Mnthsel.selectedIndex].text + " " + 
     Yrsel.options[Yrsel.selectedIndex].text + " " + 
     Typesel.options[Typesel.selectedIndex].text + "." +
     Formatsel.options[Formatsel.selectedIndex].text;

  }
 }
 </script>
```

New Javascript code

```
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
     var Yrsel = document.getElementById("myYear");
     var Mnthsel = document.getElementById("myMonth");
     var Typesel = document.getElementById("myType");
     var Formatsel = document.getElementById("myFormat");
     var LinkUrl = Mnthsel.value + " " + Yrsel.value + " Article." + 
          Formatsel.value;
     var LinkUrl2 = Mnthsel.value + " " + Yrsel.value + "." + 
          Formatsel.value;



  if (Typesel.options[Typesel.selectedIndex].text == "Article") {
     document.getElementById("myLink").href = 
   "http://www.myOrg.org/Article/" + LinkUrl; 
    document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = "Get Article";
    }

   if (Typesel.options[Typesel.selectedIndex].text == "Calendar" && 
    Formatsel.value == "doc") {
   document.getElementById("myLink").href = 
   "http://www.myOrg.org/Article/Calendar for " + LinkUrl2 + "x";
    document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = "Get Calendar";
    }

     else {
       document.getElementById("myLink").href = 
       "http://www.myOrg.org/Article/Calendar for " + 
    LinkUrl2;
    document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = "Get Calendar";
     }

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: This is pretty rambling and contains at least 3 questions. So what's the actual question (singular)?

Comment: Sorry for rambling.  Just trying to make sure you get the whole picture.  I'll try and keep it shorter and just 1 problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

1. In your if statement you're comparing with a single `=` which
   actually performs an assignment.
2. To get the selected value from a `dropDownMenu/<Select>` You just
   `.value` on it.

Comment: [some people never learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713317/load-different-html-pages-based-on-username-javascript#comment32833341_21713317)

Comment: THANK YOU.  I got it to work.  If you want me to post my code let me know.

Comment: That would be helpful if someone has the same problem as you.